# Converting G.722 audio files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, voip

I have a G.722 RTP stream that was captured with Wireshark, and am trying to convert it to PCM using ffmpeg. I have done similar things with other codecs (like G.729), and the conversion works correctly. However with G.722, the resulting file plays back at roughly half-speed (although the pitch is correct).

I have tried various options to ffmpeg, but have yet to find the right incantation. Can anyone please help clarify what is going on and how to convert these files?

Comment: Can you maybe supply a sample, and the full, uncut `ffmpeg` command output?

Comment: Do you mean to you, directly? I am not sure I can attach a file here, nor, I think, would I want to.

Comment: You could upload the file to any sharing site (MediaFire etc), and it'd greatly help in debugging the issue. I understand though if you can't provide the file for various reasons. Having the `ffmpeg` output would still be good.

Comment: You can find the samples here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18029883/Archive.zip

One file is the RAW capture of the G.722 stream, then second is an ffmpeg conversion to PCM/WAVE. Any help is appreciated.